# Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely - Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net grid, in grid I have not used paging as that is client requirement of not using it.

Grid has template control with every column is either text box or drop down.

When I bind the grid with more than 210 records it gives me below error while saving.

```
Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.
```

To be more specific, I googled this error but could not solve this error from the solutions I found, this is the rare case where I will be having this much record in grid but this is a possible scenario.

Please advise on this.

Regards,

Dhaval Shukla

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to populate the grid?  This is usually caused by a function calling its self endlessly.